# purecss drop down menu not working

Tags: html, css

I am using trying to create vertical drop-down menu using purecss library but no success

```
purecss.io/menus/
```

My css code looks like:

```
<div class="pure-menu custom-restricted-width">
    <ul class="pure-menu-list">
        <li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-has-children">
            <a href="#" id="menuLink1" class="pure-menu-link">T-Shirts</a>
            <ul class="pure-menu-children">
                <li class="pure-menu-item">
                    <a class="pure-menu-link" href="t-shirts-rundhals-tx-2-1,-1-2-.html">Rundhals</a>
                </li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item">
                    <a class="pure-menu-link" href="t-shirts-v-neck-tx-3-1,-1-3-.html">V-Neck</a>
                </li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item">
                    <a class="pure-menu-link" href="t-shirts-longsleeve-tx-4-1,-1-4-.html">Longsleeve</a>
                </li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item">
                    <a class="pure-menu-link" href="t-shirts-tanktop-tx-124-1,-1-124-.html">Tanktop</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Even I copy paste the sample code from their documentation and its not working too

**[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/sukitudino/edit?html,output)**

Comment: It's not all your code, is it? Have you put those css and javascript links as in the example?

Comment: ya on jsbin i have added css and js like to library but no result , also on my code i have it for no result too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working fine just add css for `custom-restricted-width` because your `pure-menu` div content 100% width of the screen, so that you can not show the dropdown menu.

```
.custom-restricted-width{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: You could also add your code into a grid. Pure CSS offers a method similar to Bootstraps grid. http://purecss.io/grids/

Comment: Glad to help you :)